# Send custom mail with styles

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to send an entire webpage via e-mail. I receive it in Mail.app in my Mac and i can see it fine. But when i see it in gmail or hotmail, It didn't get the styles

How can I do this correctly. Or how to transform the webpage to PDF or PNG and send it via Mail [I can't install anything to the server]

Edit: It send all the information but without Style

My code:

```
$mail = $_POST['mail'];

    if(($Content = file_get_contents("http://google.com")) === false) {
        $Content = "";
    }

    $Headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $Headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    $Headers .= "From: a@a.com <a@a.com>\n";
    $Headers .= "Reply-To: a@a.com\n";
    $Headers .= "X-Sender: <a@a.com>\n";
    $Headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n"; 
    $Headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n"; 
    $Headers .= "Return-Path: <a@a.com>\n";  

    if(mail($mail, $subject, $Content, $Headers) == false) {
        //Error
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Sending a modern web page via email = bad idea. GMail is probably striping out all JavaScript and some other content to prevent malicious email. Browser comparability is already a nightmare you don't want to add email clients to that game.

Comment: Hahah @AustinL. you are right, but which other alternative do I have? Re-create the webpage with simple JS?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Send a report via e-mail, but I want to know if it a way to do it without re-build that screen. If not i will change all the webpage inside a $var and send it via email

Comment: You can use much the same template but define all the CSS inline and remove all JavaScript. That said when doing email you are better off making a new email template than trying to get an exiting page to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all external style sheets . All the styles on the page should be inline or defined within the page